# Usage of "presumptuous"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

I was under the impression that the word presumptuous means

> rude in a pushy way, or asking too much because one thinks of oneself as an important being.

I read the dictionary.com and Merriam Webster definitions, and it looks like it matches my understanding, but Merriam Webster example has the following sentence:

> The *presumptuous* doctor didn't even bother to explain to me the treatment that I would be receiving.

This to me sounds more like *conceit* than *presumptuous* because the doctor isn't asking something from the patient. Is my understanding of the word correct? Or is it a term that can be used simply as *arrogant*?

Comment: It means to presume the facts of a situation and act accordingly. So the doctor presumes that the patient couldn't understand an explanation of the treatment or would willingly forgo an explanation. This naturally often comes across as arrogance. The doctor may or may not be conceited (i.e., vain).

Comment: This is a nice change in perception. The doc is just old-school. A few decades ago no one expected a doctor to explain much.

Comment: @deadrat that explains. So there's another example: "I hope I won't be considered presumptuous if I offer some advice". Does this mean I am presuming that someone can't figure things out by himself?

Comment: It's presuming that advice is welcome from the speaker, so not really.

Comment: It will depend on the context of the situation. It could be that the person has told you he's taking a course of action that you think will be disastrous. You're now presuming you know better. Or it could be that the person has told you that he doesn't know what to do. He may know that he needs advice, but you're presuming (as @TheNate says) that he will welcome advice from you. In either case, you're presume some facts that you don't really know are true but act as though they were.

Comment: So, rat: why not lump all that into an answer and score some points?